# Different OpenAPI schema in FastAPI depending on environment

Tags: openapi, fastapi

We have a FastApi application that is hosted behind a reverse proxy.

The proxy authenticates the user using Kerberos and adds a X-Remote-User HTTP header to the request.

This header is required by the FastApi application. Here is an example route:

```
@app.get("/user/me")
async def get_user_me(x_remote_user: str = Header(...)):
    return {"User": x_remote_user}
```

The X-Remote-User header is required for the request which is expected behavior.

When we now open the [Swagger Ui](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/#interactive-api-docs), the header is documented and when clicking on "Try it out", we can provide the header value.
[image]
This behavior is great for development, but in all other cases it is undesired, because that header is provided by the reverse proxy. For instance, we generate clients using [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) and the clients then all require the X-Remote-User parameter in their requests.

Hence, it would be useful to have a configuration that distinguishes between the environments. If we are behind a reverse proxy, then the generated OpenAPI Schema by FastApi should not include the X-Remote-Header, otherwise if we are in development, it should be included.

What I did so far:

- I checked the documentation about [security](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/) and also some [source code](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/tree/master/fastapi/security) of these modules, but I was not able to find a solution.
- In the documentation, I read the section [Behind a Proxy](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/), but nothing there points me to a potential solution.
- I also read about [Middleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/), but again, no solution.
- We could change the generated OpenApi schema. I sketched this in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63932596/4173303), but this is not a very elegant solution

Does anyone have a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `APIKeyHeader` to remove the X-Remote-User header from the API signature, but still enforcing the header to be present.

```
from fastapi.security import APIKeyHeader

apiKey = APIKeyHeader(name="X-Remote-User")

@app.get("/user/me")
async def get_user_me(x_remote_user: str = Depends(apiKey)):
    return {"User": x_remote_user}
```

When the header is not present, we get a "403 Forbidden". If it is present, we retrieve the header value.

The Swagger UI now has a button "Authorize" where we can fill-in the value of the X-Remote-User for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to generate the OpenApi schema as described in the documentation [Extending OpenAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/). After the generation, remove the X-Remote-User from the schema. In the configuration could be a flag that the application it is behind a reverse proxy to execute the code conditionally:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.openapi.utils import get_openapi
from MyConfig import Config


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items():
    return [{"name": "Foo"}]

if Config.reverse_proxy:
    def custom_openapi():
        if app.openapi_schema:
            return app.openapi_schema
        openapi_schema = get_openapi(
            title="Custom title",
            version="2.5.0",
            description="This is a very custom OpenAPI schema",
            routes=app.routes,
        )
        // remove X-Remote-User here
        app.openapi_schema = openapi_schema
        return app.openapi_schema


    app.openapi = custom_openapi
```

However this is not a very elegant solution, as we need to parse the Json string and remove the different deeply-nested occurrences of the X-Remote-User header everywhere. This is prone to bugs resulting in an invalid schema. Furthermore it could break if new Rest endpoints are added.

Answer (score 0):

A new param will be soon available for `Header`, `Query` and other to exclude elements from the openAPI output: `include_in_schema=False`

Example:

```py
def test(x_forwarded_for: str = Header(None, include_in_schema=False)):
    ...
```

Here the patch state: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/3144